# Getting html file from path for an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, system.io.file

I have a html file that is an email template. In my Azure function I want to read the file in with 'HtmlDocument', manipulate it, then send it out as an email to members.

How do I read the file 'hero.html' from my Azure Function app? And then once I publish it to Azure will I need to change the way the file is read?

FYI - doc.Load accepts a string, file path and other parameters

Here is what I tried and a pic of my project.

```
        //var emailBodyText = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Templates", "hero.html"));
        var mappedPath = Path.GetFullPath("hero.html");

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(mappedPath);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including a file when I publish my azure function in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537758/including-a-file-when-i-publish-my-azure-function-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 11):

You can get the function directory name from `ExecutionContext` parameter, if you add it to the function:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ExecutionContext context)
{
    var path = $"{context.FunctionDirectory}\\Templates\\hero.html";
    // ...
}
```

See details in [Retrieving information about the currently running function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function).

Comment: the file hero.html doesn't get put into the function directory

Comment: @user1186050 That's a different question, you can put it there (e.g. manually, or with source control integration)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way I can upload this file when I publish to Azure? I want to access this file in the function when running on Azure. I'm a little confused as to accessing it on the server

Comment: I'm just trying to get an answer from somebody! :)

Comment: IMO, downvoting because of unrelated questions won't help

Comment: Set the file to Build Action = Content and Copy to Output Director = Copy Always.

Answer (score 0):

Can access path directly in Azure function code (@"C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Templates\EmailTemplate\CommonStatusTemplate.html")