# Azure Functions equivalent of the App_Data folder

Tags: azure-functions

My Google fu is failing me.

I have a JSON file I need to store locally and be read by my function on startup. Where can I include this file in my VS functions project, and how can I access the file?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

[Including a file when I publish my azure function in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537758/including-a-file-when-i-publish-my-azure-function-in-visual-studio)

I think this might be useful to leave on SO because I kept searching for "azure functions app_data."