# How do I access a local file in an Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, local

I have created an HTTP Function in VSCode using C# net6.0, and all I want to do is read from a local json file and give me a result. Using `context.FunctionDirectory` leads me to `...\bin\Debug\net6.0\...`. In older .net stuff, I would expect to copy the file to the output directory as an artifact, but I'm coming up lacking on how to do that in .net 6.0 in an Azure Function. My poor Google skills have only led me down the path of adding a configuration file, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Is there an easy way to copy this file to the Function Directory so I can retrieve it during execution? Also, I've only run this locally, so I'm hoping whatever solution I find will also work when I push this up to Azure.

Comment: have you tried using the [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#iwebhostenvironment-interface)?

Comment: See [Including a file when I publish my Azure function in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70691516/5436889)

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutionContext` parameter provides the `FunctionDirectory` in .NET 6.

> Is there an easy way to copy this file to the Function Directory so I can retrieve it during execution?

This is one of the ways to access the information from the code while it is in execution/running:

.NET 6 Azure Function
[image]

Refer to the GitHub Azure Functions Host [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function) on using the `FunctionAppDirectory` on the function which is in running/executing state.